# How to delete SQLite table IF EXISTS without calling execSQL?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Coming from a background of being taught Javascript with Douglas Crockford where he places a high emphasis on not using eval, and an educational background that it's just bad form to use general blanket methods like exec that pose security vulnerabilities, is there anyway to delete a SQLite table if it exists w/o having to resort to `execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE)`? The [current method documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) seems to suggest execSQL is the only way as the only delete method is:

> Convenience method for deleting rows in the database.

and deleteDatabase is for databases, not tables.

Comment: It's actually `execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);` - Don't use the **'** on object names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute DROP TABLE IF EXISTS, use `execSQL`.

This is not JavaScript, where `eval` would be able to execute a JavaScript statement from within JavaScript.
SQL is a language different from Java, so constructing an SQL string is the only way to execute SQL.

There is no security vulnerability unless an attacker would be able to control the contents of the `DATABASE_TABLE` symbol.

If the `execSQL` function is too generic for you, create a `dropTableIfExists` helper function that formats the string for you (and that [quotes the identifier](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) correctly).